# VS 2012 and VS 2012 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have installed VS 2012 RC on windows 7. Now I'm going to install official VS 2012. 
Now I'm not sure if need to uninstall RC firstly?
And also I'm not sure if it will upgrade RC or install it side by side?

Answer (score 0):

You should uninstall the RC first.